# Angular directive open date picker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I have an Angular directive that includes a form with a datepicker.  I am trying to create a function to keep the button click from calling submit on the form.  I can not determine where to find the .opened attribute.  When I was performing the open with ng-click everything worked.  Below is sample code.

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="editAlert.$valid && vm.handleSubmit()" name="editAlert" id="editAlert" class="buffer-bottom" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="effectiveDate">Effective Date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" is-open="dpEffectiveDate.opened" ng-model="alertMsg.effectiveDateFmt" name="effectiveDate" id="effectiveDate">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.openDateHandler($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
    </div>
    <p class="help-block" ng-show="editAlert.effectiveDate.$error.endBeforeStart">Effective date must be before expire date.</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

I also tried passing dpEffectiveDate into the openDateHandler function.

Below is my Typescript function

```
openDateHandler = ($event) => {
  $event.preventDefault();
  //dpDate.opened = !dpDate.opened;
}
```

How do I access the .opened attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is prevent the submit behaviour, simply add 'type="button"' to your button element.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.openDateHandler($event)">
```

By default, a button inside a form will act as a submit button unless it's given a different type.

You shouldnt need to mess with the opened state of a date picker to prevent a form submitting.